# Django Admin edit related custom user model

Tags: django, python-3.x

I have the following models:

```
class Student(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)

class Teacher(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)
```

All the django admin docs specify that I can edit the Student in the User view, but I have multiple models that have a related user so that solution does not work. I would like to be able to edit the User from the Student and the Teacher views.

Comment: Can't try it out now but I'll let you know

Comment: Thank you, it did help, but not the first answer and rather the second one, with the plugin django_reverse_admin